# Trying to print a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a file with a list of cities I'm trying to print and I cannot get them to print.

**Code**

```
citylist = open(os.path.join(folderpath, 'Clipped_Cities.dbf'))
print citylist
```

**Result**

```
<open file 'C:\\Users\\Michaelf\\Desktop\\Test_Folder\\LabData\\Clipped_Cities.dbf', mode 'r' at 0x030B6B78>
```

How can I actually print the cities within the folder `Clipped_Cities.dbf` instead of the path?

Comment: is the .dbf file a dBase data file?

Comment: You are trying to print a file object instead of that files contents.

Comment: I'm not sure here is what it says in properties

Comment: OpenOffice.org 1.1 Spreadsheet (.dbf)

Comment: fp = open('some_file', 'r') will give you a file reader. Then you need to do either: fp.read() to get the full content or fp.readlines() that will give you an array of lines of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but you're trying to print a file object instead of that files contents as mentioned by *@n1c9* in the comments.

```
citylist = open(os.path.join(folderpath, 'Clipped_Cities.dbf'), 'r')
for line in citylist:
    print line
```

You need to specify read permissions, then iterate over the file object.

Also a few things,

- Instead of setting a variable to the file object like you are. it's better to use the `with as` method as it gets rid of it after you're done.
- You may want to use `f` as the name of the object is a popular convention.

So,

```
with open(os.path.join(folderpath, 'Clipped_Cities.dbf'), 'r') as f:
# Iterate over file...
```

---

**Note**

If if you don't want blank lines in between your lines as pointed out by *@zondo*, you probably want to do something like

```
print line.replace('\n', '')
```

This simply replaces the newline character in the string with `''`.

Or simpler,

```
print line.rstrip()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108761/discussion-on-answer-by-signal-trying-to-print-a-list-in-python).